# Getting Error: Cannot find module 'node:util' when executing the commnd "appium"

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-java

C:\Users\win>appium

Error: Cannot find module 'node:util'

Require stack:

- C:\Users\win\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\build\lib\cli\extension-command.js
- C:\Users\win\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\build\lib\cli\driver-command.js
- C:\Users\win\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\build\lib\cli\extension.js
- C:\Users\win\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\build\lib\main.js
- C:\Users\win\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\index.js

  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)

  at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)

  at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)

  at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)

  at Object. (C:\Users\win\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\lib\cli\extension-command.js:17:1)

  at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)

  at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)

  at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)

  at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)

  at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)

  at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)

  at Object. (C:\Users\win\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\lib\cli\driver-command.js:2:1)

  at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)

  at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)

  at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)

  at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)

Comment: Your node version is probably ancient

Comment: Deleting node_modules & package-lock then "npm install" worked ?